# NSURLProtocol is not getting all requests

Tags: ios, nsurlprotocol

So I have implemented my own NSURLProtocol sub class. I registered it when app launches.

I tried to print all requests in `canInitWithRequest:`, however while running, it's not getting all the requests, just a few domains.

Is there anything I should notice or be careful? Any possible reasons? What did I miss? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on how you registered it.  You can register it for use with NSURLConnection (and, IIRC, the shared NSURLSession), or you can register it for use with other NSURLSessions individually.  If a request happens in a session that your protocol isn't registered in, your protocol won't see it.

Comment: It's been a while, but any chance you could add an example to your answer on how to register for more general use case?

Comment: You can register one broadly by calling `[NSURLProtocol registerClass:[MyProtocolClass class]]`.  You can register it for a specific session by adding `[MyProtocolClass class]` to the `protocolClasses` array in the session configuration before creating the session.

Comment: It is also worth noting that things like WKWebview run out-of-process and are not subject to protocol handlers.  The same is true for some of the video player APIs and possibly others.